# How can I add these lines with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to add lines like this to my webpage but unsure how to do so[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IBgL.png)

i dont know how to do this

Comment: [<hr>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr)

Comment: As a side note, if you see something on a website and want to know how it's done, inspecting it with the browser's dev-tools can be a great way to learn.

Comment: Those would be better implemented with borders rather than extra markup.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```css
main {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

  <h2>IMAGE</h2>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
</main>
```